# Copy constructor signature without const keyword C++

Tags: constructor, copy, constants, signature

Why does compiler give an error on line 1, even though copy constructor will not be called in line 1 and the error vanishes if copy constructor signature is declared as const?

```
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int n) :
            i(n) {
        cout << "A ctor" << endl;
    }
    A(A& a) :
            i(a.i) {
        cout << "A c-ctor" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1(1);
    A a2 = 2; // line 1
    A a3 = a1; // line 2

}
```

//The above code was compiled with MinGW

Answer (score 1):

This is an effect of implicit constructor call. Try to add "explicit" clause before the constructor declaration

```
....
explicit A(int n) :
        i(n) {
    cout << "A ctor" << endl;
}
....
```

Given that, compiler would complain like "*conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'A' requested*". This sheds some light why:

```
A a2 = 2; // line 1, original, fails on explicit construction
A a2 = A(2); // line 1, auto-substituted by compiler if implicit construction allowed
```

So, if our compiler can find a way to automatically convert one type to another via constructor call, it auto-instantiates it here.

Also this gives the answer "why 'const' required for copy constructor":

```
A a2 = A(2);
A a2(A(2)); // default implementation of '= operator'
```

Here, A(2) is temporary object. Thus, compiler would try to get non-const reference to it and fails (because it's rvalue - otherwise you can try to change something that will die at the end of line).

Comment: But it does not give any error if copy constructor is kept private. I guess that means compiler isn't substituting any temporary object.

Comment: I suppose, in that case compiler would use '= operator' as default field-by-field assignment.

Comment: I don't think so, as assignment operator would never be called at the time of construction. You can verify that by keeping it private. It is not calling copy constructor even if it is kept public, that means there is no temporary object as well.